# Errno 2 No such file or directory "I get this error even with one line of code that should work"

Tags: python, text-files

I'm just starting with python and I want to make a simple login system with text files. Everytime I run the code I get this error. It doesn't even make the text file. Before this, I could run my code and it made a file but now it doesn't. I tried just one line of code to open a text file but that doesn't work either.(line of code: f = open("demofile.txt")) I also tried to google it, no solution. I don't know what to do?

```
def AskForAccount():
    status = input("Do you have an account? ")
    if status == "yes":
        logIn()
    elif status == "no":
        createAccount()
    else:
        print("Type yes or no, please.")
        AskForAccount()

def createAccount():
    name = str(input("username: "))
    password = str(input("password: "))
    f = open("dataBank.txt", 'r')
    info = f.read()
    if name in info:
        return 'Name unavailable'
    f.close()
    f = open("dataBank.txt", 'w')
    info = info + ' ' + name + ' ' + password
    f.write(info)

def logIn():
    username = str(input("username: "))
    password = str(input("password: "))
    f = open("dataBank.txt", "r")
    info = f.read()
    info = info.split()
    if name in info:
        index = info.index(username)+1
        usrPassword = info[index]
        if usrPassword == password:
            return "welcome back," + username 
        else:
            return 'password incorrect'
    else: 
        return 'Name not found'

print(AskForAccount())
```

Comment: Does the folder where your script is actually has the file `dataBank.txt`?

Comment: You're accessing your files using just their filenames, i.e., you do not specify the folder(s) where said files are located. Python will thus look for said files in the "current working directory" which depends on how you are running your script.

Comment: You should also consider using the with statement (`with open(filename, 'r') as f:`), then you don't need to close the file explicitely and it will even be closed if there is an exception inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know whats your logic but to create a file you need to use a `w+`
try it by de the code

```
def AskForAccount():
    status = input("Do you have an account? ")
    if status == "yes":
        logIn()
    elif status == "no":
        createAccount()
    else:
        print("Type yes or no, please.")
        AskForAccount()

def createAccount():
    name = str(input("username: "))
    password = str(input("password: "))
    try:
        f = open("dataBank.txt", 'r')
        info = f.read()
        if name in info:
            return 'Name unavailable'
        f.close()
    except:
        return 'Data base donest exists. creating one...'
    f = open("dataBank.txt", 'w+')
    info = info + ' ' + name + ' ' + password
    f.write(info)

def logIn():
    username = str(input("username: "))
    password = str(input("password: "))
    f = open("dataBank.txt", "r")
    info = f.read()
    info = info.split()    
    if username in info:        
        index = info.index(username)+1
        usrPassword = info[index]
        if usrPassword == password:
            return "welcome back," + username 
        else:
            return 'password incorrect'
    else: 
        return 'Name not found'

print(AskForAccount())
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get in `f = open('demofile.txt')` is because `open` takes an additional argument 'mode' whose default value is 'r' for read. If the passed filename does not exist you get the described error.
Use `f = open('demofile.txt','w')` instead for writing to a file. This creates a new file if the filename does not exist.